# Find $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln{3x}}{\ln{2x}}$ without l'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

How do you find the following limit without using l'Hospital's rule???
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln{3x}}{\ln{2x}}
$$

Comment: $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *Jonas Meyer's suggestion*

> $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$

Explicitly, What can you say about:

$$
\frac{\ln{3x}}{\ln{2x}} = \frac{\ln{3}+\ln{x}}{\ln{2}+\ln{x}} =\frac{\frac{\ln{3}}{\ln{x}}+1}{\frac{\ln{2}}{\ln{x}}+1}
$$
As $x\to 0$?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\log(3x)=\log\left(\frac32\cdot2x\right)=\log\left(\frac32\right)+\log(2x)
$$
Clearly $$
\frac{\log(3/2)+\log(2x)}{\log(2x)}=1+\frac{\log
(3/2)}{\log(2x)}
$$
It is now more readily apparent considering $\log(3/2)$ is a constant while $\log(2x)$ grows without bound.

Answer (score 1):

Using Jonas's idea:

$$\lim_{x\to0^{+}} \frac{\ln 3x}{\ln 2x} = \frac{\ln 3 + \ln x}{\ln 2 + \ln x}.$$ What happens to $\ln x$ as $x\to0^{+}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln(ax)}{\ln(bx)}=\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{\ln(a)+\ln(x)}{\ln(b)+\ln(x)}={\lim_{x \to 0^+}\large\frac{1+\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(x)}}{1+\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(x)}}}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using nonstandard analysis. If $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, it will be a positive infinitesimal, and the limit will be the standard part from plugging this in.
$$st\left(\frac{\ln(3x)}{\ln(2x)}\right) = st\left(\frac{\ln(3)+\ln(x)}{\ln(2)+\ln(x)}\right)=st\left(\frac{\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(x)}+1}{\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)}+1}\right)=\frac{st\left(\frac{\ln(3)}{\ln(x)}+1\right)}{st\left(\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)}+1\right)}=\frac11=1$$