# Finding $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln3x/\ln2x$

Tags: limits

I need some help with a limit calculation.  $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln3x/\ln2x$. I tried to multiply with $3x/3x$ and $2x/2x$ to get $3x\ln3x \to 0$ and $2x\ln 2x \to 0$, but that leaves me with $2x/3x\to 2/3$ and it should be $1$.

Comment: Do you know l'Hopital's rules? Why do you think it should be $1$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503927/find-lim-x-to-0-frac-ln3x-ln2x-without-lhospitals-rule

Comment: I don't know l'Hopital's rule, will read up on it.

Thanks for finding a previous answer. I couldn't =(

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

$$\frac{\log 3x}{\log 2x}=\frac{\log x+\log 3}{\log x+\log 2}$$

Now multiply the rightmost expression above by

$$\frac{\frac1{\log x}}{\frac1{\log x}}$$

Comment: +1 Nice...I thought of doing that, but only *after* you posted! Big sigh!

Comment: That leaves me with ln(3)/ln(x). ln(x) would be small and negative so ln(3)/ln(x) would be negative inf?

Comment: No @iveqy, that leaves you with $$\frac{1+\frac{\log 3}{\log x}}{1+\frac{\log 2}{\log x}}$$ Now, what's the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac k{\log x}\;\;,\;\;k=\text{a constant}\;?? $$

Comment: Ah, I get it, it will be 0 since log(x) -> -inf.

The only question I still haven't figured out is what was wrong with my initial approach. That approach worked on other limit tasks.

Comment: You seem to have taken the limit for some expressions but **not** for others. That's almost always forbidden and it usually leads us to wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

By L'Hopital, $$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\;\dfrac {\ln 3x}{\ln 2x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \;\dfrac{\frac d{dx}(\ln 3x)}{\frac d{dx}(\ln 2x)} = \lim_{x\to 0^+}\;\dfrac{\frac 3{3x}}{\frac 2{2x}} = 1$$